# Fiware generic enablers list

Tags: artificial-intelligence, fiware

Today i checked Fiware enalber home page and to my surprise there are very few generic enablers are listed around 18.
https://catalogue-server.fiware.org/enablers

Earlier it used to be 50-60!
Can someone tell what happened to other GEs and is there a GE or GEi for Artificial intelligence?

Answer (score 0):

The reduction was annouced at the [Porto Global Summit](https://www.slideshare.net/FI-WARE/fiware-global-summit-fiware-today-and-tomorrow) - see slide 15 of the presentation

> The requirements for being a FIWARE/Incubated GE:
>
> - Fitting in a "Powered by FIWARE" architecture
> - Committed technical support
> - Contribution to common roadmap
> - Relevant Adoption
>
> There is a periodic revision at TSC level and this reduced the list
>   from 48 GEs + 4 Incubated GEs to 13 GEs and 9 Incubated GEs (which
>   includes several new additions)

The core mission of FIWARE has been clarified around context data management only - those GEs which were not a good fit are not actively promoted as FIWARE.

The latest catalogue of GEs can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/Fiware/catalogue)